# Send email via AWS SES using Laravel Mail class

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am trying to send email using AWS SES service and the Laravel Mail class (`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail`).

I would like to set to the `ConfigurationSetName` to be able to recieve notifications via AWS SNS.

At the moment, I am using the Laravel Mail class using SES and it is working but not the notifications.

Is there any way to do this? Or do I have to use the SesClient always to assign the `ConfigurationSetName`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-configuration-sets-in-email.html), you can specify the `X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET` header on the email.

From a Laravel perspective, the easiest way is to specify the headers to be sent right from your Mailable:

```
public function build()
{
    $this->markdown('emails.creditcard.added');

    $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
        $message->getHeaders()
                ->addTextHeader('X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET', '####');
    });
}
```

You could also do it using the Mail Facade, since it has an underlying `Swift_Message` instance. For example:

```
Mail::send('emails.creditcard.added', [], function ($message) use($user) {
    $message->to($user->email)
        ->getSwiftMessage()
        ->getHeaders()
        ->addTextHeader('X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET', '####');
});
```

If you want to add this header to all emails, you could also listen to the `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending` event and add the headers from there.

```
public function handle(MessageSending $event)
{
    $headers = $event->message->getHeaders();
    $headers->addTextHeader('X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET', '####');
}
```

I also verified that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add on to @Mozammil's answer.

In case you want to add multiple headers:

```
return $this->view('mail-template')
    ->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
        $headers = $message->getHeaders();
        $headers->addTextHeader('X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET', 'my-configuration-set');
        $headers->addTextHeader('ANOTHER-HEADER', 'header-value');
    });
```